# ORAEXT : XPST0017: Cannot find a matching 5-argument function named

Tags: java, xml, oracle, xslt, saxon

While doing XSLT transformation, I have a requirement to call Datasource inside xsl. I am using ora-ext to achieve it. But I am getting  Cannot find a matching 5-argument function named and 4-argument matching function on use of the query-database function of ORAEXT.

Full stacktrace:

> Static error at char 1 near {...t_code','jdbc/JDBCDataSourc...} in
>  expression in xsl:value-of/@select on line 1 column 1575
>  
>         XPST0017: Cannot find a matching 5-argument function named
>    {http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc}lookup-table().
> For diagnostics on calls to Java methods, use the -TJ command line option or set the Configuration property FeatureKeys.TRACE_EXTERNAL_FUNCTIONS

This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
 xmlns:sql="http://ns.saxonica.com/sql"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:java="http://saxon.sf.net/java-type"
 xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
 exclude-result-prefixes="java saxon xsd xsi xsl sql"
 extension-element-prefixes="saxon sql"
 >
<xsl:template match="Order">
<Parameter>
<xsl:attribute name="name">ACT_CODE</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="value">
 <xsl:value-of select="oraext:lookup-table('ACT_CODE_MTDT', 'prdt_id','1159', 'act_code','jdbc/JDBCDataSource')"/>
</xsl:attribute>
</Parameter>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Kindly suggest, if I am missing on something. Suggest me if any jar apart from ojdbc6.jar is required.

Also, I'm not able access [this](http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc) URL.
Is that the namespace got changed, or there something missing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you are running Saxon as your XSLT processor (we can tell from the form of the error messages) but you are trying to call an extension function that has been defined by Oracle as an vendor extension for their own XSLT processor. That ain't gonna work.